# Is all the code in an ASP.NET Core project consist of middlewares?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, middleware, .net-7.0

I am taking some lecture on Udemy and from the lectures what I interpret is that all the code in a .net core project are some kind of middlewares? I mean is there a specific boundary where the middleware ends and the actual code of the app starts? Infact can anyone tell me the simplest and most precise definition of middlewares? A definition that I consider as the final verdict. Thanks

I tried all the websites related to .net core but did not find the precise definition which I can take as the final verdict.

Comment: It's only _middleware_ if it's a function (usually a closure, but not necessarily) that is invoked as part of the _request-handling pipeline_ which is set-up in your `Configure()` method (or wherever you see the `.UseXXX()` methods). Not all C# code in a project will be added to the pipeline directly, such as injected services and library code. However, the short-simple answer is "yes": insofar as any middleware function can potentially _handle_ a request and return a response - and indeed, the Routing and/or Controller Action endpoint-handlers are implemented as middleware funcs.

Answer (score 0):

No, not all the code in an ASP.NET Core project consists of middlewares. Middleware is a software component that is used to handle requests and responses in a pipeline. It is typically used to perform tasks such as authentication, authorization, logging, and routing.

The actual code of the app is the code that is responsible for handling the business logic of the application. This code is typically located in the controllers and services of the application.

The boundary between middleware and the actual code of the app is not always clear-cut. Some middleware components may also perform some business logic. However, in general, middleware is used to handle common tasks that are not specific to the business logic of the application.

Here is a simple and precise definition of middleware:

Middleware is a software component that is used to handle requests and responses in a pipeline.

This definition is precise because it does not specify any specific tasks that middleware can perform. It also does not specify where middleware should be placed in an application. This allows middleware to be used in a flexible way to handle a variety of tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much @Panda. I got it 'Flexibility' is the main feature of middleware.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) doc:

> Middleware is software that's assembled into an app pipeline to handle requests and responses. Each component:
>
> - Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the pipeline.
> - Can perform work before and after the next component in the pipeline.

> Request delegates are used to build the request pipeline. The request delegates handle each HTTP request.

> Request delegates are configured using Run, Map, and Use extension methods. An individual request delegate can be specified in-line as an anonymous method (called in-line middleware), or it can be defined in a reusable class. These reusable classes and in-line anonymous methods are middleware, also called middleware components.

So usually not all the code of the ASP.NET Core project will be places in middlewares (though you can if you want to), but all the code handling the request should be in some way called by some middleware (for example MVC's controllers code is paced separately but is invoked by corresponding pipeline).

Note that ASP.NET Core project can consist not only from request-response handling but for example can have some background task processing via [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) which are not middleware's in common ASP.NET Core sense.